# Build Agent can't select a date in DateTimePicker

Tags: selenium, tfs, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium test which selects a date on a datetimepicker of an ASP.NET MVC5 view. The problem is that the Selenium code runs perfect when I run the test in Visual Studio. When the code is running on a TFS Build Agent running on my own machine the build agent can't select a date. After the click on the date the selected date should be highlighted as an indication the date is selected. This happend in Visual Studio but it doesn't on the build agent.

My Selenium code looks like this:

_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

```
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(<someurl>);

            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            //Auto 3
            //IWebElement query = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn_car_1024"));
            var query = _driver.FindElementsByClassName("btn_car").FirstOrDefault();
            query.Click();

            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            //Select a date in the calendar
            //_driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("datepicker")).Click();

            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            var elements = _driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("day"));

            var dateLinkText = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day.ToString();

            var selectedElements = elements.Where(p => p.Text == dateLinkText);
            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            if (selectedElements == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("SelectedElements null");
            }
            if (selectedElements.Count() == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Length null");
            }
            var selectedElement = selectedElements.FirstOrDefault();

            selectedElement.Click();
            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            //Select time
            var timeDropDownList = _driver.FindElementById("Time");
            timeDropDownList.Click();

            var selectElement = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement(timeDropDownList);
            selectElement.SelectByText("10:00-11:00");
```

Comment: Use explicit wait instead of implicit and wait more more than 20 seconds (perhaps 1 minute?)

Comment: I've added this explicit wait on the datepicker element. But the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this problem. This problem was caused because the click on the selected date became too early. The click was done already before the whole page was fully loaded. This happened after the first time the page was hit after the application was deployed. 
The solution for me was to add a Thread.Sleep after the click on the selected date.